# Cannot send message using the server stmp.atlas.cz

Tags: mail.app

I have googled this and there have been already lots of people facing this same issue; but after trying the various suggested methods nothing changes and I just wanted to give it one last shot and see if anyone can take a look at my specifics and help me fix it.

I receive emails flawlessly on the mail app, but cannot send them without receiving this message: Cannot send message using the server stmp.atlas.cz:mariya@atlas.cz

I suspect it may have to go with the foreign (Czech) email server? Anyway, here's the setup.

[image]

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it so much. If this is just because my email server is too obscure that's alright, it's not too big a deal, I'm still receiving emails through the app and that's more important.

Comment: First; switch of the Auto detect & maintain. Then double-check your port & SSL settings with your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

The URL of the server name is probably wrong. The correct server name is smtp.atlas.cz instead of stmp.atlas.cz.

SMTP: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
STMP: Simple Transportation Management Protocol or Sodium trimetaphosphate (the latter is not even a protocol but a substance ;-))